# Move multiple UIImageView objects

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I want to add multiple `UIImageView` objects at run time. I just read that it's possible through `NSMutableArray`.

But I also want to move all the `UIImageViews`. Is it possible to track which `UIImageView` I touched?

Please help me. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may need to rephrase your question but I'll see if I can help you out. To find what view is being touched, you can define the `touchesBegan` method in your view controller.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; //gets the touch object
    [touch.view thisIsAMethod]; 
    //once you declare touch, you can access what view is being touched with touch.view

}
```

Also, if you want to move a lot of `UIImageViews` at once, you can make them all `subviews` of one `UIView` by calling

```
[oneBigUIView addSubview:oneUIImageView];
```

for every `UIImageView`. Then you can change the position of the `UIView` to move them all at once, since the coordinates of each `UIImageView` are in relation to their `superview`.